# Change font colour and type in PgAdmin 8.2 / 9.1

Tags: postgresql, fonts, pgadmin

I use dark theme on windows, and my pgAdmin changes dark theme too.
It's great for me, except the black column tittle when i open the table:

[image: Black Colum Tittle]

I try to change the font colour to gray via File -> Options -> Browser -> UI Miscellaneous. I click 'OK', but nothing happens.

i open the UI Miscellanious again, and the font doesn't change (still black Tahoma).. :(

[image]

Somebody, please help me..

Answer (score 3):

So it appears that pgadmin uses incompatible default color attributes from gtk. Namely "Windows Text" Color for the foreground and "Input Box" Color for the background.

To change the colors in ubuntu, 
1. right click on the desktop -> change desktop background
2. from the Appearance Preferences Menu click the Theme Tab
3. Highlight your current theme then click Customize
4. Click the Colors tab, and change the "Windows: Text" , and "Input boxes: Background" to the colors you want for pgadmin.
5. Restart pgadmin to see the color changes.

Unfortunately this has the effect of changing your desktop color settings, and it is somewhat difficult to adjust such that you don't mess something else up. Pgadmin -- I advise you to maybe submit a bug report to pgadmin with some tag to the effect of "Incompatible Default GTK Color Classes Used on UI Rendering"